# Simulating Monte Carlo p-values (t-distribution)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, monte-carlo

Suppose we are interested in testing the null hypothesis that the mean of a normal population is 10 against the alternative that it is greater than 10. A random sample of size 20 from this population gives 9.02 as the sample mean and 2.22 as the sample standard deviation.

My question is two part:

1. I know that I'll have to use T-test to get our test statistics (since population $\sigma^2$ is unknown), but is the null distribution the t distribution (with $n-1 df$) or Normal with mean 10 and (unknown) $\sigma^2$ variance
2. I know that CDF of null density equals $U$ (uniform random variable). I then set it equal to the CDF and solve for our sample random variable. I can then simulate in `R` and calculate a T value to get a p-value. I am wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this in `R`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "underlying distribution" (doesn't the problem assert this is normal?) and "null density" (again, doesn't the problem say the data have a normal distribution?).

Comment: @whuber thanks for pointing this out. I was also concerned with this wording. To answer your first question - yes, the population is normal. But, after doing further research, the null distribution is the distribution that the test statistics takes so, in fact, the null distribution would be $t[n-1]$ and not $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$.